# How to costumize the font of the titles in the table of contents

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, tocloft

I have two problems with my document tex. I can't add elements to content table and the second problem I want that the titles in the content table have the style as figured in the attached figure and without using the \usepackage{tocloft}, because I caused a problem with the chosen chapter style.
Thank you in advance.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,microtype}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
 \usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\usepackage{caption}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}
 {\makebox[\textwidth]{\titlerule[0.8ex]\quad\textls{\chaptername}\      \thechapter\quad\titlerule[0.8ex]}}
{1ex}
{\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\centering\huge\textls[50]}
[\titlerule]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}
{\makebox[\textwidth]{\titlerule[0.8ex]}}
{1ex}
{\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\centering\huge\textls[50]}
 [\titlerule]

\begin{document}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
 \chapter*{Tables des mati\`{e}res}

 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
 \listoffigures
 \listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction G\'{e}n\'{e}rale}
\chapter{Premier chapitre}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A `\tableofcontents` solve the first problem as far I see

Comment: Since you use `titlesec`, would you consider using `titletoc` from the same family? It's just a matter of using `\scshape`  up to the section level. Do you need colour too?

Comment: `titlesec` and `tocloft` together are a weird combination